# How would i add a get function to existing script

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery , but i now need to get the data from another url

```
var RequiredStarters = 7;   // ENTER THE NUMBER OF STARTERS YOUR LEAGUE REQUIRES

$(document).ready(function () {
   $("td.two_column_layout .report").each(function(index, element){
    if($(this).find("tr").length !== +RequiredStarters + 3 && $(this).attr("id") !== "InvalidLineup"){
        var target = $("#InvalidLineup").find("tbody");
        $(this).find("a").each(function(){
            target.append("<tr><td>" + $(this)[0].outerHTML + "</td></tr>");
        });
    }
   });
});



<table class="homepagemodule report" id="InvalidLineup" align="center" cellspacing="1">
<caption><span>Submit Valid Lineups</span></caption>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

where would i put the get function example

```
$.get('http://%HOST%/%YEAR%/options?L=%LEAGUEID%&O=06', function (data)
```

Comment: This section of the code makes no sense `.length !== +RequiredStarters + 3 `. Are you sure you've posted the correct code?

Comment: yes i have a var for the # there

Comment: What are you doing with the output of the GET??

Comment: @JasonEvans: `+RequiredStarters` casts `RequiredStarters` to an int, even if it's another type before (e.g. string). Then `3` gets added and compared to the number or <tr>-Tags

Comment: By getting the data from another URL, are you saying that you are trying to parse the data from another page? Because, if so, you don't have that page loaded into the DOM by doing a get here, you just have the HTML itself inside of the data variable, which is just textual data at this point with no way to select unless you append it to the current DOM tree. Adding it to an invisible DIV would work. For example: $("#invisibleDiv").html(data). Then, select from $("#invisibleDiv").

Comment: Dan , i edited my post to show the html the data  will be appended to , i just need to incorporate a get function to pull that data from another page on my site

Comment: Yes Reeno , i need to add 3 to each var , to account for a few th tablerows that are always populated to each table